# How to add customer Id in table Magento 2

Tags: magento2, database, customer-account, customer-attribute, customer-session

This is my code but I can't get the customer Id that's currently logged in.

```
public function checkotp(){

    //db connection
    $this->_resources = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance()
    ->get('Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection');  
    $connection= $this->_resources->getConnection();
    $tableName = $this->_resources->getTableName('otpp');

    $ckotp = $_POST["getotp"];

    $dates = date("Y-m-d");

        // SELECT DATA
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM otpp WHERE `otp`='$ckotp' AND `dates`='$dates'";
    $result = $connection->fetchall($sql); 

    $cd = $result[0];

    $dc = $cd['otp'];

    if($dc == $ckotp){

        $om = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $customerSession = $om->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
        if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) {
            $customerId=   $customerSession->getCustomer()->getId();
            $sql = "INSERT INTO " . $tableName . "(phone, otp, dates,cust_id) VALUES ('$phone', '$randcode', '$dates', '$customerId')";

            echo "<div class='success'>";
            echo "Your mobile number verified";
            echo "</div>";
        }
    }
    else{
        echo "Invalid Otp";
    }

    $connection->query($sql); 
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to try this code :

```
$om = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$customerSession = $om->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
if($customerSession->isLoggedIn()) 
{
      $customerId = $customerSession->getCustomer()->getId();
}
```

Comment: This is not working @Dhiren

Comment: have face any error while you try this code?

Comment: yes..just added abover code but can't able to display cutome rid

Comment: try to put the above code in try.....catch block and check is that any error occured.

Comment: If above things help you, please accept it as answer, So it will help other in community as well.